# disable button from another view controller in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a button that is initialized dynamically.. I want to disable that button from another UIViewController.

I am using this code:

The button is 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aboutus;

and then i try to disable it this way:

```
OtherViewController * view2 = [[OtherViewController alloc]      initWithNibName:@"view2"    bundle:nil];
view2.aboutus.enabled=NO;
```

but the button would still be enabled.. any ideas why?

Comment: The button has not loaded yet because the view does not yet exist. It will load in viewDidLoad of OtherViewController. This is why you need to set a flag then use that flag to disable the button in viewDidLoad, as EIJay said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a public `BOOL` property:

```
@property(nonatomic) buttonEnabled;
```

on `OtherViewController`.  Set that value to whatever you want (YES or NO) and then in viewDidLoad:

```
aboutus.enabled = buttonEnabled;
```